# Flag wasn't helpful

Tags: discussion, flagging

I flagged the following post as spam since it wasn't a question at all.

[Secure file I hope](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/209181/secure-file-i-hope)

Seems to be copy/paste of text on a Google webpage.

> Your account, your data.
>       The Google data archive you started on April 28, 2019 is ready. It contains your Android Device Configuration Service, Bookmarks, Calendar, Classroom, Contacts, Data Shared for Research, Drive, Fit, G Suite Marketplace, Google Help Communities, Google Input Tools, Google My Business, Google One, Google Pay, Google Photos, Google Play Books, Google Play Console, Google Play Games Services, Google Play Movies & TV, Google Play Store, Google Shopping, Groups, Handsfree, Hangouts on Air, Home App, Keep, Location History, Mail, Maps, Maps (your places), My Activity, My Maps, News, Posts on Google, Profile, Purchases & Reservations, Saved, Search Contributions, Street View, Tasks, and Textcube data. It will be available for you to download until May 5, 2019.
>       Manage archives
>       Download archive
>       ￼
>       This message was sent to you because you recently used Google's Download your data service. Privacy Policy | Terms of Service
>       ￼
>       List item

The decline message is:

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

Seems a question like this would surely require a moderator. Being a user with such low rep, I'm really making the effort to contribute and don't understand what would be more appropriate? Is this the result of not choosing the right 'flag category'? Perhaps a comment would be better (even though I don't have the rep to comment)?

Answer (score 4):

It's not spam, for one. The question appears to be (from the title) if the file that was created by the process is secure.

Secondly, even if it was spam mods should only be informed if something needs to be handled urgently or if it is serious. The question did not require serious or urgent action.

Else, just use the normal voting buttons to vote to close.

Comment: We'll have to 'agree to disagree'. The post is of such low quality it shouldn't be considered anything better than spam. There's not even a question! I don't know who flagged the question though I'm surprised that this meets your own standards as a valid question.

Comment: In regards to your second point, I simply marked the question as spam and have no control over what queue it lands in.

Comment: "Spam" has a specific meaning. "Low quality" is its own flagging category.

Comment: [Per help docs](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down), spam should be flagged and flagging should be favored over downvoting. `Downvoting should be reserved for extreme cases...Instead of voting down:..flag it` Interesting to find the OP is no longer available...

Comment: When did I say "downvote"?

Comment: `Else, just use the normal voting buttons to vote to close.`

Comment: Ok, you've read the help docs in a skewed way and you've read my comment in a skewed way. That's simply not what the help doc says and that's not what I said. Please go over the words and read more carefully.

Comment: You do not appear to understand the difference between "spam" and "low quality" and you are confusing "vote to close" with "downvoting". You have also completely misread the help doc where it says, "If the post is spammy or offensive, flag it". Low quality is not spam, so invoking that line is not valid.